# Android screen Navigation

Tags: android

I see in many apps this way to navigate on Android as you see in the image below . When the screen is touched switch to the next screen and the blue circles below turn orange but i dont know how to do it. is it a library?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See ViewPager (http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html) for the swipe navigation, and PagerTabStrip (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html#).